# unable to run for loop in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am experimenting with Vue and encountered a problem.

using v-for doesn't update the div with content.

I'm using Vue CDN for now and adding vue components in a single JS file

JS:

```
  Vue.component('vue-content', {
   data: function() {
    return {
        data: []
    }
},
template: `
    <div id='content'>
        <p> This is the content section </p>
        <div v-for="info in data">
            <p> {{ info.title }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
`,
created: function() {
    this.test();
},
methods: {
    test: function() {
        var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
        var apiCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
        apiCall.onload = function() {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(apiCall.responseText);
                console.log(data);      
            }
            else {
                console.log("Unable to load data, Please try later!!!!");
            }
        }

        apiCall.open("GET", url, true);
        apiCall.send();
    }
}

})

new Vue({
el: "#app"
})
```

HTML :

```
   <div id="app">
    <vue-navbar></vue-navbar>
    <vue-content></vue-content>
    <vue-footer></vue-footer>
   </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Is displaying content this way not possible?? or should I use the cli way or doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not update the `data` array you specified for Vue.js. Instead you just create a new variable with the same name. That is not how it works.

Usually, you have to reference `this.data`. But as your scope (and thus, `this`) within the API callback is different, you have to make a reference to the correct `this`. E.g. using `var vueThis = this;`.

```
methods: {
    test: function() {
        var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
        var apiCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var vueThis = this;
        apiCall.onload = function() {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                vueThis.data = JSON.parse(apiCall.responseText);
                console.log(vueThis.data);      
            }
            else {
                console.log("Unable to load data, Please try later!!!!");
            }
        }

        apiCall.open("GET", url, true);
        apiCall.send();
    }
}
```